# FirstWhere method is not working properly in Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections, null, find, push

I have $balance that is returned from another function like this:

```
$balance = {
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "ABS",
            "y": 1450
        },
        {
            "name": "PBT",
            "y": 1200
        },
        {
            "name": "Краситель",
            "y": 1000
        },
        {
            "name": "PP",
            "y": 750
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have also collection called $statistics like this:

```
$statistics = [
    {
        "name": "ABS",
        "data": []
    },
    {
        "name": "PP",
        "data": []
    },
    {
        "name": "PBT",
        "data": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Краситель",
        "data": []
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is pushing all ***y*** 's of $balance to corresponding $statistics by matching their ***name***.
Here is short description of my code:

```
foreach ($balance["data"] as $firm){
                    $statistics->firstWhere('name', $firm->name)['data']->push($firm->y);
                }
```

However, I'm getting *Call to a member function push() on null* error. Can anyone help me find out the problem

Comment: That error is thrown because `firstWhere` is returning null because the `name` you're looking for is not in the collection. And you can't use the method `push` on null. You should check that `firstWhere` is returning something